# Redirect sub.domain.com to /var/www/subfolder and sub.domain.com/api to /var/www/apifolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, server, virtualhost

I want to redirect the /api folder to a new documentRoot (new virtualhost) from the already existing virtualhost

```
domain.com -> /var/www/domain
sub.domain.com -> /var/www/sub
sub.domain.com/api -> /var/www/api
```

And should be recursive, so `sub.domain.com/api/v1` should also go to `/var/www/api`.
Is this even possible with apache?

Any suggestions to make this less confusing would be appreciated ;p

Comment: I don't see an issue here. You don't even need rewriting for this. Just define the hosts and an `Alias` directive for the "api" part.

Comment: It is not clear what you actually mean by "recursive". Please explain that statement.

Comment: Well when I declare an Alias, it works for `sub.domain.com/api` but not for `sub.domain.com/api/v1`. I'd like it to work for /api and everything after it. That's what i meant with recursive.

Comment: Well for that you do need a redirection rule. But that appears straight forward. You match `/api` and redirect. Can you please add your own attempt for that, so that we can fix what might be wrong with that? Thanks!

Comment: Well can I just make a new VirtualHost file and say `ServerName sub.domain.com/api` with a `documentRoot /var/www/api`? I thought you couldn't do subfolders in ServerName

Comment: I added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said above in the comments you can simply define virtual hosts for this. You do not need any redirection commands at all:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    <Directory /var/www/domain>
        # ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com

    Alias /api /var/www/api/index.php    
    <Directory /var/www/api>
        # ...
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub
    <Directory /var/www/sub>
        # ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This obviously assumes that your `API` is implemented by a script called `/var/www/api/index.php`. You certainly can save that implementation as whatever you like, for example `/var/www/api`. However that does not look very realistic to me, APIs are typically implemented on a scripting base and scripts usually require include files, so a folder holding the implementation certainly does make sense. And I doubt you want to throw all those files into `/var/www`, so I *assume* that `/var/www/api` is meant to hold the implementation.

I tested this setup locally, it does work for me.

Comment: The /api still doesn't work.

`RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/api.+ /api [L,QSA]
        Alias /api /var/www/api/

        <Directory "/var/www/api">`

Comment: It gives me a 404 from the sub.domain.com virtualhost

Comment: And if you turn around the configuration as changed in the answer? Sorry, been a while since I did such stuff...

Comment: That's oke I'm already glad you're helping me. But no still doesn't work. Too bad I know so little of mod_rewrite. Can these characters maybe help? `(.*)`

Comment: Can't really work when I'm tired. I will try again tomorrow. Thanks anyway for your help! If you come up with another option to try, feel free to post it.

Comment: I updated the answer, removed the rewriting. Turned out that it is indeed not required at all, just as I commented initially.

Comment: Thank you so much, that should work. And yes I indeed have a index.php where the program starts. I will try and update you in a sec

Comment: It worked! It went to the index.php for all the subdomains. But the php framework didn't expect and could handle the request. But thank you for everything. I think I'll just create another subdomain and cry about not knowing enough about mod_rewrite. Well thankk you again for your effort

Comment: What do you mean by "But the php framework didn't expect and could handle the request"? Maybe it relies on the original request path? In _that_ case you would need rewriting again to clean it...

Comment: I don't know exactly what it was, but it didn't expect the request in that way. But I'll use another subdomain